# ¿Cómo se debe exportar correctamente en JavaScript con Node.js?

Tags: java, nodejs, exportar, module.exports

tengo un archivo main.js el cual contiene toda la estructura de mi aplicación. Ahora lo que quiero es separar las funcionalidades por archivo para que el código sea sostenible y escalable.

Este es mi archivo main.js:

```
// Modulo para crear tareas
const cron = require('node-cron');
const axios = require('axios')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const colors = require('colors')
require('dotenv').config()
const token = process.env.JWT_TOKEN

/*
*   Función asincrona que obtiene las grabaciones por limite de fechas y cantidad de grabaciones
*   @params {from} 'Fecha de inicio' YYYY-MM-DD
*   @params {to} 'Fecha de termino' YYYY-MM-DD
*   @params {limit} 'Cantidad de grabaciones' MAX LIMIT = 300
* */
const getMeetingRecordings = async () => {
    const response = await axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/accounts/me/recordings',
        qs: {
            status: 'active'
        },
        params: {
            page_size: 30
        },
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            'User-Agent': 'Zoom-Jwt-Request',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        json: true
    })

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve(response)
    })
}
/*
* Función que permite la eliminación hacia la papelera de una reunión
* params {meetingId} 'ID de la reunión'
*
* */
const deleteMeeting = async (meetingId) => {
    const response = await axios({
        method: "DELETE",
        params: {
            action: 'trash'
        },
        url: `https://api.zoom.us/v2/meetings/${meetingId}/recordings`,
        qs: {
            status: 'active'
        },
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            'User-Agent': 'Zoom-Jwt-Request',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        json: true
    })
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (response.data.status === 200) {
            resolve(response.data)
        } else {
            reject(response.data.status)
        }
    })
}

/*
* Función que permite la descarga de archivos mp4 desde una URL
* @params {filename} 'Nombre del archivo'
* @params {url} 'Dirección URL de descarga'
* */
const downloadMP4 = async (fileName, url) => {
    console.log('Iniciando la descarga....')
    // Crea el archivo en el directorio establecido
    const directory = path.resolve(__dirname, 'files', `${fileName}.mp4`)
    // Ejecutar la consulta HTTPS y comienza la descarga
    const response = await axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: url,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Zoom-Jwt-Request',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        responseType: 'stream'
    })
    // Crea el archivo en el directorio obtenido en la respuesta de la petición
    response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(directory))
    // Retornamos una promesa para manejar la descarga
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Si la descarga ha terminado retorna el valor de true
        response.data.on('end', () => {
            resolve(response)
        })
        // Si la descarga ha tenido un error retorna el valor de false
        response.data.on('error', (err) => {
            reject(response)
        })
    })
}

const deleteMP4 = (fileName) => {
    fs.unlinkSync(`./files/${fileName}.mp4`)
}


// Luego continua toda la ejecución de las funciones y la lógica. 
// (El archivo original es muy extenso, usaré este pequeño trozo como ejemplo).
```

Ahora yo me acostumbre a utilizar el patron MVC entonces creo una carpeta llamada controllers y dentro de ella separo los archivos por módulos, por ejemplo:

- controllers>zoomController.js
- controllers>systemController.js

Entonces, separé los archivos de la siguiente manera:

zoomControllers.js

```
// Modulos Node
const axios = require('axios')
require('dotenv').config()
// Token JWT
const token = process.env.JWT_TOKEN
/*
*   Función asincrona que obtiene las grabaciones por limite de fechas y cantidad de grabaciones
*   @params {from} 'Fecha de inicio' YYYY-MM-DD
*   @params {to} 'Fecha de termino' YYYY-MM-DD
*   @params {limit} 'Cantidad de grabaciones' MAX LIMIT = 300
* */
const getMeetingRecordings = async () => {
    const response = await axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/accounts/me/recordings',
        qs: {
            status: 'active'
        },
        params: {
            page_size: 30
        },
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            'User-Agent': 'Zoom-Jwt-Request',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        json: true
    })

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve(response)
    })
}
/*
* Función que permite la eliminación hacia la papelera de una reunión
* params {meetingId} 'ID de la reunión'
*
* */
const deleteMeeting = async (meetingId) => {
    const response = await axios({
        method: "DELETE",
        params: {
            action: 'trash'
        },
        url: `https://api.zoom.us/v2/meetings/${meetingId}/recordings`,
        qs: {
            status: 'active'
        },
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            'User-Agent': 'Zoom-Jwt-Request',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        json: true
    })
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (response.data.status === 200) {
            resolve(response.data)
        } else {
            reject(response.data.status)
        }
    })
}

// Pruebas unitarias
// Obtener las reuniones
// getMeetingRecordings().then(result => console.log(result.data))


module.exports = {
    getMeetingRecordings,
    deleteMeeting,
}
```

systemController.js

```
// Paquetes Node
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const axios = require('axios')
/*
* Función que permite la descarga de archivos mp4 desde una URL
* @params {filename} 'Nombre del archivo'
* @params {url} 'Dirección URL de descarga'
* */
const downloadMP4 = async (fileName, url) => {
    console.log('Iniciando la descarga....')
    // Crea el archivo en el directorio establecido
    const directory = path.resolve(__dirname, 'files', `${fileName}.mp4`)
    // Ejecutar la consulta HTTPS y comienza la descarga
    const response = await axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: url,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Zoom-Jwt-Request',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        responseType: 'stream'
    })
    // Crea el archivo en el directorio obtenido en la respuesta de la petición
    response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(directory))
    // Retornamos una promesa para manejar la descarga
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Si la descarga ha terminado retorna el valor de true
        response.data.on('end', () => {
            resolve(response)
        })
        // Si la descarga ha tenido un error retorna el valor de false
        response.data.on('error', (err) => {
            reject(response)
        })
    })
}

const deleteMP4 = (fileName) => {
    fs.unlinkSync(`./files/${fileName}.mp4`)
}


module.exports = {
    downloadMP4: downloadMP4,
    deleteMP4: deleteMP4
}
```

Finalmente el archivo que importará los controladores
Program.js

```
// Modulo para crear tareas
const cron = require('node-cron');
const colors = require('colors')
require('dotenv').config()
const token = process.env.JWT_TOKEN
// Controladores
const systemController = require('./controllers/systemController')
const postgreController = require('./controllers/postgreController')
const zoomController = require('./controllers/zoomController')
const googleController = require('./controllers/googleDriveController')

zoomController.getMeetingRecordings()
    .then(recordings => {
        const {data} = recordings
        data.meetings.map(meeting => {
            meeting.recording_files = meeting.recording_files.find(file => file.file_type === 'MP4' && file.status === 'completed') //  || {} Esto se puede usar en caso de que no hay archivo MP4
        })
        const filterMeetings = data.meetings.filter(meeting => {
            const {duration, total_size} = meeting;
            return total_size > 20971520 && duration > 10;
        })
        filterMeetings.forEach(meeting => {
            systemController.downloadMP4(meeting.id, `${meeting.recording_files.download_url}?access_token=${token}`)
                .then(download => {
                    console.log(colors.green(download.data))
                })
                .catch(download => console.log(colors.red(download.data)))
        })
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Y aquí comienza el problema, cuando inicio el Program.js con Node se ejecuta pero las funciones no hacen lo que hacen cuando estaban todas juntas en el Program.js, es decir, no funciona correctamente. Me asegure de cambiar los directorios, ya que si el archivo está en una carpeta superior, por ejemplo, en la función `download` del `systemController` debo retroceder un directorio para acceder a la carpeta files que está en la raiz del proyecto.

Otra cosa es que he visto que muchas veces utilizan

```
modules.export = {
  downloadMP4,
  deleteMP4
}
```

Para así usar destructuring

```
const {downloadMP4, deleteMP4} = require(./controllers/systemController.js)
```

No sé si estoy mezclando conceptos, he tratado de ver vídeos pero no consigo quedar con una idea clara de como hacerlo correctamente, o si no se puede con destructuring o si hay que hacerlo de una manera estandar, etc.

Agradecería si alguien me puede asesorar en esta interrogante.

Comment: ¿La consola no te devuelve ningún error? Si es así, compártelo por favor. Voy a responder a la 2da parte de tu pregunta más abajo mientras tanto.

Comment: Si, errores de directorios. Es decir, cuando estaba en la raíz del proyecto mi ruta a files era ./files pero al mover el código a una carpeta superior, debía devolverme ../files. Había cambiado en algunas partes pero me faltaban algunas rutas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exports:

```js
modules.export = {
  downloadMP4,
  deleteMP4
}

modules.export = {
  downloadMP4: downloadMP4,
  deleteMP4: deleteMP4
}
```

Ambas opciones son exactamente lo mismo, devuelven un objeto. La diferencia es como se escribe: cuando usas el mismo key en el objeto como nombre de variable, puedes construir el objeto añadiendo directamente la propiedad. Se hace así porque es muy común en Node o React pasar parámetros y mantener el nombre de la variable a lo largo de tu aplicación.

```javascript
const val = 1;
const obj = {
  val,
  valor: val,
  otroValor: val
};

obj.val // 1
obj.valor // 1
obj.otroValor // 1
```

---

Destructuring:

Puedes aplicar destructuring **a cualquier objeto**. Destructuring es una forma que obtener la propiedad de un objeto a la que asignas el mismo nombre de variable, nada más:

```javascript
const obj = {
  val: 1
}

var { val } = obj; // con destructuring
console.log(val) // 1

var val = obj.val; // sin destructuring
console.log(val) // 1
```

Como ves, el destructuring es una forma de mantener un código legible, además de ser tremenda herramienta cuando deseas recuperar muchas propiedades, de esta forma:

```javascript
const obj = {
  val1: 1,
  val2: 2,
  val3: 3
}

// usando destructuring
var {val1, val2, val3} = obj;
console.log(val1, val2, val3) // 1, 2, 3

// sin destructuring
var val1 = obj.val1;
var val2 = obj.val3;
var val3 = obj.val3;
console.log(val1, val2, val3) // 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora estoy utilizando destructuring, me parece más amigable y funciona a la perfección!  Gracias!

Comment: Genial! Es lo mejor, y se puede aplicar en arreglos también, para que lo tengas presente, por ejemplo const [idx1, idx2] = ['1', '2'];